# form mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

i've got the following queries that i need to execute in php. Problem is i need the set queries before the execution of the main query. The set queries are

```
SET @center = GeomFromText('POINT(33.3666667 35.1666667)');   
SET @radius = 1;   
SET @bbox = CONCAT('POLYGON((',   
X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',',   
X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',',   
X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',',   
X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',',   
X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, '))'   
);
```

and the main query is

```
SELECT
users_profile.id,
GLength(LineString(users_profile.location,GeomFromText('POINT(33.3666667 35.1666667)'))) * 100 as distance

FROM 
users_profile

WHERE 
Intersects( users_profile.location, GeomFromText(@bbox))
AND (GLength(LineString(users_profile.location,GeomFromText('POINT(33.3666667 35.1666667)'))) * 100)  < 10

ORDER BY distance
```

How can i execute this in PHP? i cannot do it as 4 different queries nor can i do it in 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can execute the first query like that. Try writing it as one stored procedure and then calling it from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#37870) that might help.  I haven't used or testing it, so YMMV.

Comment: i went the mysqli way after all. It is far from ideal due to the way mysqli executes multiple queries. The ideal would be to reform the 4 queries into 1 but all my tests failed miserably.